# Reversing String in c using loops....

Tags: c, string, loops, reverse

I have created a code reverse a string but for some reason it is not working. But I think my logic is right. Then why is it not working??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char words[100];
    int i=0;
    printf("Enter a word/sentence: ");
    scanf("%s", words);

    while (words[i]!='\0') {
           ++i;
    }
    printf("\nThe Reverse is: ");
    while (i<=0) {
         printf("%s",words[i]);
         i--;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s"..` -> `scanf("%99s"...`, lookup `strlen`

Comment: `printf("%s",words[i]); --> printf("%c", words[i]);`

Comment: `while (i<=0) {` is `i` always going to be greater than zero. Hence this condition is always false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your program.

1. After you have reached the end of the string.You should do i-- as your array index of i will be pointing to `'\0'`.
2. Your while loop checks for `<=` but it should be `>=`.
3. Use `%c` for printing chararcters. `%s` is used to print strings and not char.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char words[100];
    int i=0;
    printf("Enter a word/sentence: ");
    scanf("%s", words);

    while (words[i]!='\0') {
        ++i;
    }
    i--;
    printf("\nThe Reverse is: ");
    while (i>=0) {
       printf("%c",words[i]);
       i--;
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Always**, always **validate user input.** int rtn; `if ((rtn = scanf ("%s", words)) != 1) { if (rtn == EOF) { /* handle user canceled input */ }; /* handle input failure */}` Then the loops, `for (; words[i]; i++) {}; while (i--) printf ("%c", words[i]);` (there is no need for `stdlib.h` in the code)

Comment: Seems odd to add `i--;` before the loop when `while (i>0)` (without `=`) would do the job.

Comment: @chux without i--, i would be pointing to '\0'. As David C. Rankin  said while(i--) would do the job.

Answer (score 3):

While you already have an answer, there are a few additional points you need to consider before you have a solution that doesn't have the potential to invoke *Undefined behavior*.

First, ***always, always*** validate ***all user input.*** For all you know a cat could have gone to sleep on the `'L'` key (with millions being entered), or a more likely case, the user just decides to type a 100-char sentence (or more) which leaves 'words' as an *array of chars* that is NOT *nul-terminated* and thus not a valid *string* in C. Your loop to get the length now invokes *Undefined Behavior* by reading beyond the end of `words` off into the stack until the first random '0' is encounter or a *SegFault* occurs.

To prevent this behavior (you should really just use `fgets`) but with `scanf` you can provide a *field-width* modifier to prevent reading more than `length - 1` chars. This insures space for the *nul-terminating* character.

Further, the `"%s"` *conversion-specifier* stops conversion on the *first whitespace* character encountered -- making your `"Enter a .../sentence"` an impossibility because `scanf ("%s", words)` will stop reading after the first word (at the first *whitespace*.

To correct this problem (you should really just use `fgets`) or with `scanf` you can use a *character class* (stuff between `[...]`) as the *conversion specifier* that will read until a `'\n'` is encountered., e.g. `scanf ("%[^\n]", words)`. However, recall, that is still not good enough because more than 99-chars can be entered leaving the string un-terminated at 100 and invoking *Undefined Behavior* at character 101 (off the end of the array).

To prevent this problem (ditto on `fgets`), or include the *field-width* modifier, e.g. `scanf ("%99[^\n]", words)`. Now no more than 99-chars will be read regardless of the cat sleeping on the `'L'` key.

Putting that altogether, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 100    /* if you need a constant, define one */

int main(void) {

    char words[MAXC] = "";
    int i = 0, rtn = 0;     /* rtn - capture the return of scanf  */

    printf ("Enter a word/sentence : ");
    if ((rtn = scanf ("%99[^\n]", words)) != 1) {   /* validate ! */
        if (rtn == EOF)     /* user cancel? [ctrl+d] or [ctrl+z]? */ 
            fprintf (stderr, "user input canceled.\n");
        else                    /* did an input failure occur ? */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input - input failure.\n");
        return 1;               /* either way, bail */
    }

    for (; words[i]; i++) {}    /* get the length */

    printf ("Reversed word/sentence: ");
    while (i--)
        putchar (words[i]);     /* no need for printf to output 1-char */
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strrevloops
Enter a word/sentence : My dog has fleas.
Reversed word/sentence: .saelf sah god yM
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: The answer couldn't have been clearer. I just want to ask if there is any specific reason for the string initialiser for `words` ?

Comment: You always want to initialize your arrays to all *zero*, that way regardless of any error in logic, if you read less than `sizeof (array)` chars, your string will **always be nul-terminated** `:)`

Comment: Fair enough, just that for automatic arrays (of good enough size), it will be expensive. Nevertheless a good practice.

Comment: Initialization is cheap from an efficiency standpoint. Using the default initializer, whether with `words = ""` or `words = {0}` accomplishes the same thing. When you initialize to zero, you are only initializing the first element, all remaining elements are made zero by the default initialization process -- lightning fast, and well worth the 0.00472 microsecond or initialization time (or whatever it is in the real world).

Comment: "your string will always be nul-terminated" --> maybe.  Consider `if (rtn == EOF)`, on input error, the contents of `words` is not certain.  As much as initializing variables is a worthy guide (I an not a fan off initializing large arrays when `words[0] = 0;` would suffice and perhaps 100x faster), checking return values is even more beneficial.

Comment: Well, perhaps I should have been more clear. Since on anything other than `rtn = 1` the result is `return 1;` I assumed that as a qualification to the "your string will always be nul-terminated" statement, but yes, I agree, there are no guarantees if an input-failure occurs and you proceed with the string. Whether you do `words[0] = 0;` or `words[MAXC] = ""` it is likely to be one OP. That won't always be true when the array size grows and exceeds the combined register sizes, but point taken on large arrays, especially if repeatedly initialized within a loop.